# Regex to detect full name

Tags: regex, string, validation

I'm using a regex to detect a full name, the name need to follow these rules:

1. At least two names are required, separated by a space. Name with more than one space aren't accept.
2. The same characteres aren't allowed if they are in a sequence with 3 or more characteres.

Examples:

Accept:

1. `James Mary`
2. `James Smith Murphy`

Not accept:

1. `James Maryyy`
2. `James`

Here are the regex that i'm using, is there a way to improve this regex to only one?

1. `^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+$` this is to detec the first requirement
2. `([a-zA-Z])\1\1` this is to detect the second requirement

Comment: Note that A-Za-z is pretty restricted for a name. It think it could be like this `^(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\1\1)^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/kqjeWS/1

Comment: It's allowed, i wrote with more than one space but stackoverflow removed.

Comment: Can you use look around?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than a single regex pattern can handle. You have to deal with accented characters (`Óliver` in Spanish), different character sequences (`ASD` vs `DSA`; is `Defay` valid?), etc.

Comment: @CodeDifferent i'm handdling accented characters with `À-ü`, the `ASD` example is wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following regex:

```
(?!.*(\S)\1\1)^\S+( \S+)+
```

It first checks whether the string has not three same characters anywhere `(?!.*(\S)\1\1)`. If this check passes, then it looks for:

- `^`: start of string
- `\S+`: any combination of non space-like characters
- `( \S+)+`: any combination of space and multiple non space-like characters

It works with accented characters too.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nSYmuK/1).